# Scrollbar does not work fine on Google Chrome browser in Sencha Touch application

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, sencha-touch

I am developing a Sencha mobile web application based on Sencha Touch 2.4.1.

Now I am having a problem with the scroll bar. I did not write any scss code for the scrollbar yet. But it did not work fine. Recently I got this problem on Chrome browser only... on firefox it works fine.

Please suggest any browser which support Sencha alone.

[image]

Comment: Please, mark @klogd answer as right

Answer (score 2):

Was also having this problem, here is the explanation of what happened and a fix which worked for me:

http://trevorbrindle.com/chrome-43-broke-sencha/

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this. it might be known sencha and chrome problem.
http://www.ladysign-apps.com/developer/chrome-43-breaks-sencha-touch-modern-toolkit-and-how-to-fix-it/#.VWQveIWKJDc.twitter